# Why stream operations on Kotlin channels are deprecated?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

If you try to use any of the stream operations for channels in Kotlin (`map`, `filter`, etc...) you'll get the following warning

> Note: This API will become obsolete in future updates with
>   introduction of lazy asynchronous streams.
>   See issue [#254](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/254).

I'm not sure I totally understand the discussion about issue **#254**. Why will these operations become obsolete?

If I'm correct right know the problem is, that these stream operations run regardless if there is any **subscriber** *(since channels are hot, I'm not sure why that's a problem...)*, and the direction would be to *optimise them*, so that they run only when there is a subscriber?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are deprecated because the Flow operators can be used instead and they don't want to redefine the operators for channels.

Edit:
You can use the Flow stream operators on a Channel via [consumeAsFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/consume-as-flow.html).

Comment: could have been just a comment, but basically, it's correct

Comment: Yes, but Flows and Channels are different, Flows are cold and in some cases I want to model my data sources, so that it has a hot stream.  So I have to use channels, with deprecated operators

Comment: Channel can be consumed as flows, using `consumeAsFlow`.